# How can I make images in a grid all the same height without stretching them?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a bestsellers section for an e-commerce website I am working on, but some of the product images are of different heights. I'm using CSS grid to lay it all out since that is easiest for me, but a problem I am having is that [I can't figure out how to make the images the same height without stretching them and making them look weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kYIP.jpg)

HTML:

```html
<!-- BEST SELLERS -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bestSellers">
            <h2>Best Sellers</h2>

            <div class="bestSeller bestSeller1">
                <img src="assets/product-1.jpg" alt="">
                <p>Red T-Shirt</p>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="bestSeller bestSeller2">
                <img src="assets/product-2.jpg" alt="">
                <p>HRX Shoes</p>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="bestSeller bestSeller3">
                <img src="assets/product-3.jpg" alt="">
                <p>HRX Track pants</p>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="bestSeller bestSeller4">
                <img src="assets/product-4.jpg" alt="">
                <p>Blue Polo Shirt</p>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
//  BEST SELLERS
.bestSeller1 {
    grid-area: bestSeller1;
}
.bestSeller2 {
    grid-area: bestSeller2;
}
.bestSeller3 {
    grid-area: bestSeller3;
}
.bestSeller4 {
    grid-area: bestSeller4;
}

.bestSellers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "bestSeller1 bestSeller2 bestSeller3 bestSeller4";
    

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}

.bestSeller {
    img{
        width: 100%;
        // height: 550px;
    }
}

.checked {
    color: #FF6200
}
```

Things I have tried:

- [Setting all the images to have a height of 550px.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY8Lv.jpg) I don't like how it makes the images look weird since it is stretching them.
- [`object-fit: contain`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHe8j.jpg) The image sizing messes up

Please let me know if there are any solutions to this!

Comment: try adding ```object-fit: contain;``` on the image it won't stretch the image

Comment: You're setting the width and height explicitly, but if you want the aspect ratio to stay the same you can only set 1. Try `height:550px;` only.

Answer (score 1):

Set image to fit its parent and add `object-fit: cover;` in CSS.

```
.bestSeller {
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: The height is perfect but for some reason parts of the left and right of the image get cut off.

Comment: That's because the image size has not the same aspect ratio. You can use `object-fit: contain;` instead, but this will not set the images in same height, but the parts of the image will not get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I provided a solution for your issue, I hope that's you are looking for:
I used viewport unit vw to set the height of the grid row, try to change the value depends on your viewport width `grid-template-rows: 35vw;`, and rectify the heading title h2, I rectified also your Html code:

```css
    
.bestSellers {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-rows: 35vw;
}

.bestSeller {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bestSeller img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
 
h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.checked {
    color: #FF6200
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bestSellers">

        <div class="bestSeller bestSeller1">
            <img src="assets/product-1.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Red T-Shirt</p>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <h2>Best Sellers</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="bestSeller bestSeller2">
            <img src="assets/product-2.jpg" alt="">
            <p>HRX Shoes</p>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bestSeller bestSeller3">
            <img src="assets/product-3.jpg" alt="">
            <p>HRX Track pants</p>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bestSeller bestSeller4">
            <img src="assets/product-4.jpg" alt="">
            <p>Blue Polo Shirt</p>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```